# direction of a dc motor with the help of 2 5 pin relays

Tags: relay

I want to change the direction of a dc motor with the help of 2 5 pin relays without using any switch. Can anyone suggest the wiring diagram please?

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTnW8z.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Reversible motor control using two 5-pin relays.*

```
RLY1  RLY2  MOTOR
OFF   OFF   OFF
ON    OFF   Forward
OFF   ON    Reverse
ON    ON    OFF
```